# "property 'textField' not found on object of type 'MainUI *'"

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5

I have multiple text fields on one view controller. My .m and .h are below. I'm new to Xcode and Objective-C overall so please kind if this is just a stupid mistake.

.h:

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MainUI : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *letters;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *par;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *basicSym;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *numLetters;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *mainBack;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *mainNext;

@end
```

.m:

```
#import "MainUI.h"

@interface MainUI ()

@end

@implementation MainUI

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn: (UITextField*)theTextField {
    if (theTextField == self.textField) {
        [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
@end
```

The error is at the if `(theTextField == self.textField) {` help please?

Comment: I don't see a textField property defined in your provided header code. You have "letters" and "numLetters" UITextField properties, but no "textField" property.

Comment: self.textField does not match any of the properties you have defined in MainUI.h. Did you mean to use self.letters or self.numLetters?

Comment: Would i have to do this for each text field? for this view I only have two, but more on others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just trying to make the keyboard go away when the user presses Return while the cursor is in a textfield, this should be sufficient:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn: (UITextField*)theTextField {
    [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it will work for all text fields, as long as you've set your controller as the delegate for all text fields.

Comment: Ok, this didn't work. It did not go back on press of return. Anymore help?

Comment: Did you set your controller as the delegate for all text fields? It will work if you have done so. Set a breakpoint on the first line in the method. If it is being called, then you have correctly set the delegate. If it isn't being called, then you haven't.

Comment: How do I set the controller as the delegate?

Comment: I Got it, Thanks! Amazing how forgetting one step messes up everything.

Comment: Got busy and forgot to remark it! Thanks for mentioning it as I would have never remembered. (Memory loss, think I need an upgrade)